# if-else python program example

Tags: python, if-statement

I just wrote a code for the if-else control statement,It is as follows:

```
y = input("Enter a number : ")
x = input("Enter another one: ")

if (x > y) and (x == 6):
  print(x)
else:
  print(y)
```

I inputed y = 3 and x = 6 ,
The answer I get is 3.

What could be my error?

Comment: That's what this code does. What did you _expect_?

Comment: That's wrong output. This prints 3.

Comment: Note.No need for parenthesis: (x > y) --> x  > y .Anyway - the code works fine..

Comment: Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then edit your question to tell us what you expected, and why you expected that. Why do you say there's an error? And what is the error?

Comment: your issue is for Python 3, `input()` returns a string, and `'6'` is not `6`, convert to `int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's only whole numbers, you need to convert the inputs to integers.

If my assumption is wrong, convert to floats

```
y = int(input("Enter a number : "))
x = int(input("Enter another one: "))

if (x > y) and (x == 6):
  print(x)
else:
  print(y)
```

Answer (score 1):

That is the expected output of the code. 
In your case, you have provided x=6 and y=3 so the program would hit first its condition which is:
if (x > y) and (x == 6) which would be true and output would be 6.

I believe you have mistaken x and y values if you swipe X and Y input you might expect different output.

```
x = input("Enter value of X: ")
y = input("Enter value of Y: ")

if (x > y) and (x == 6):
  print(x)
else:
  print(y)
```

INPUT: x = 3, y =6

OUTPUT: 6

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they are all numbers.

```
y = int(input("Enter a number y: "))
x = int(input("Enter another one x: "))
print('x:', x) if (x > y) and (x == 6) else print('y:', y)
```

output:

```
Enter a number y: 3
Enter another one x: 6
x: 6
```